# Combine some data from multiple lines

Tags: sed, awk

Trying to combine data into one line where some fields match.

```
12345,this,is,one,line,1
13567,this,is,another,line,3
14689,and,this,is,another,6
12345,this,is,one,line,4
14689,and,this,is,another,10
```

Output

```
12345,this,is,one,line,1,4
13567,this,is,another,line,3
14689,and,this,is,another,6,10
```

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear on which fields lines should match.

Comment: Sorry bout that. All but the last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F',' '{if($1 in a) {a[$1]=a[$1] "," $NF} else {a[$1]=$0}} END {asort(a); for(i in a) print a[i]}' < input.txt
```

Works well with given example.

Here is commented file version of the same awk script, **parse.awk**. Keep in mind that this version use only first field as unified row indicator. I'll rewrite it according author's comment above (all fields but the last one).

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {   # BEGIN section is executed once before input file's content
    FS=","   # input field separator is comma (can be set with -F argument on command line)
}

{   # main section is executed on every input line
    if($1 in a) {   # this checks is array 'a' already contain an element with index in first field
        a[$1]=a[$1] "," $NF   # if entry already exist, just concatenate last field of current row
    }
    else {   # if this line contains new entry
        a[$1]=$0   # add it as a new array element
    }
}

END {   # END section is executed once after last line
    asort(a)   # sort our array 'a' by it's values
    for(i in a) print a[i]   # this loop goes through sorted array and prints it's content
}
```

Use this via

```
./parse.awk input.txt
```

Here is another version which takes all but the last field to compare rows:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {   # BEGIN section is executed once before input file's content
    FS=","   # input field separator is comma (can be set with -F argument on command line)
}

{   # main section is executed on every input line
    idx=""   # reset index variable
    for(i=1;i<NF;++i) idx=idx $i   # join all but the last field to create index
    if(idx in a) {   # this checks is array 'a' already contain an element with index in first field
        a[idx]=a[idx] "," $NF   # if entry already exist, just concatenate last field of current row
    }
    else {   # if this line contains new entry
        a[idx]=$0   # add it as a new array element
    }
}

END {   # END section is executed once after last line
    asort(a)   # sort our array 'a' by values
    for(i in a) print a[i]   # this loop goes through sorted array and prints it's content
}
```

Feel free to ask any further explanation.

Comment: Would be good if you explained what was going on here, then i would +1 it.

Comment: It would be better if you used `SUBSEP` to separate the elements of your index: `idx = idx SUBSEP $i` otherwise "a bc" and "ab c" are ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and sort):

```
sort -nt, -k1,1 -k6,6 file | 
sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(\([^,]*,\).*\)\n\2.*,/\1,/;ta;P;D'
```